# Android-PHP-MySql: How to improve this tutorial

Tags: java, php, android, mysqli

This is my first time asking for something here. I'll try to be as clear as possible.

I followed this great tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xtVHvifaKC4

Here's the php file:

```
<?php 

$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","test");

$id = $_GET["id"];

$query = "Select * from my_data where id between ($id+1) and ($id+4)";

$result = mysqli_query($connection,$query);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    $array[] = $row;    
}

header('Content-Type:Application/json');
echo json_encode($array);
```

?>

And here's the function I'd like to improve:

```
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            if(gridLayoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() == media_list.size()-1){
                loadDataFromServer(media_list.get(media_list.size()-1).getId());
            }
        }
    });
```

Here're the explainations:
The php script returns 4 rows starting from the 'id' it is given.
The function in java file looks for the last element in the recyclerview, gets its id and passes it to the php which returns 4 more rows from the id it just got.

My question is as follow:
What to do if there's a gape between the "id"s? Like if the id of the first row is 1 and the second row is 23.
I'm facing this issue. And since the last id in the recyclerview is 1, the OnScrollListener is not effective because the method within it will always return rows with id from 2 to 6 (which in my case don't exist).
And I really want to get result 4 by 4 (to more or less control the amount of data the app is using).

Answer (score 0):

Okay! After some deep thinking, i found a solution.
mysqli has that option to return a number of rows starting from a point:
SELECT * FROM [table_name] LIMIT [start_point],[number_of_row_to_show]
So I modified my php file:

```
<?php 

$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","w7app");

//$id = $_GET["id"];

//$query = "Select * from media where id between ($id+1) and ($id+4)";

$start = $_GET['start'];
$total = 4;

$query = "SELECT * FROM media LIMIT $start,$total";

$result = mysqli_query($connection,$query);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    $array[] = $row;    
}

header('Content-Type:Application/json');
echo json_encode($array);
```

And the loadDataFromServer method is called as follow:

```
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            if(gridLayoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() == media_list.size()-1){
                //loadDataFromServer(media_list.get(media_list.size()-1).getId());
                loadDataFromServer(start + 4);
                //asuming you created an integer 'start' initialized at 0
                start = start + 4;
            }
        }
    });
```

When sending the request, it works fine:

```
Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url("http://10.0.2.2/Android/W7App/script_show.php?start=" +start)
                    .build();
```